# Laravel "artisan make:observer" fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I am trying to generate a provider using Artisan as described on the documentation page [1] by running:

```sh
    php artisan make:observer AdServiceProvider
```

However I get the following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]  There are no commands defined in the
>   "make" namespace.

Am I doing something wrong or is the documentation perhaps outdated?

http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers

Comment: This is the Laravel 5 documentation. According to your tags you use Laravel 4

Comment: @DipendraGurung has posted a more up to date solution, consider accepting his answer instead of mine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no make:observer command, neither in the documentation, nor in the command list.

As you have tagged your question you are using Laravel 4, there is no make:*** command whatsoever.

---

For Laravel 5:

To create a new provider, simply call

```
php artisan make:provider [provider name]
```

You can always get a list with all commands available by typing

```
php artisan
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers - documentation has this command, but command is not implemented at laravel v5.6

Comment: @LINKeRxUA the documentation has been recently updated 6 days ago!

If you want this feature in Laravel v5.6 you can update your laravel using, `composer update`.

Comment: @DipendraGurung Can you post a new answer with the current state? OP should accept that then; I haven’t worked with laravel for ages, you seem to know what’s new..

Answer (score 11):

Laravel **version 5.6** has recently introduced the artisan command to create an observer.

You can now issue command like,

```
php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User
```

Check the updated documentation here:-
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers